# How to order by date?

Tags: angularjs

I'm requestion content from TheMovieDB to show it (titles, images, release dates) on my website and also to store that content in my database. I was wondering if it's possible to to order this by date.

I know there's `| orderBy:'date'"` but I'm unshure on how to use it on my website.

There would be two scenarios in which I would like to order by date.

Firs scenario is when users do a search action, they can type in a movie title and my searchfunction will retrieve all titles (and release dates) from TheMovieDB and display them in a `ul`.

```
%div{"ng-controller" => "searchCtrl", :id => "container_search"}

  %input{"ng-change" => "search(searchquery)", "ng-model" => "searchquery", "ng-model-options" => "{ debounce: 500 }", :id => "search_input", :placeholder => "Search a movie!", "ng-keyup" => "clear_results()"}
  %ul#showresults
    %li.search_results{"ng-repeat" => "movie in movieList"}
      .addmovie{"ng-click" => "addMovie()"}
        %span
          Add Movie
      %img.poster{"ng-src" => "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/{{ movie.poster_path }}"}
      %span.title
        {{ movie.original_title }}
      %span.release
        {{ movie.release_date }}
```

The output of TheMovieDB http request looks like this,

```
angular.callbacks._6({"page":1,"results":[{"adult":false,"backdrop_path":"/jSNIAKD5pCyhjgJL9HZ3hsu19yD.jpg","genre_ids":[28,12,80],"id":206647,"original_language":"en","original_title":"SPECTRE","overview":"A cryptic message from Bond’s past sends him on a trail to uncover a sinister organization. While M battles political forces to keep the secret service alive, Bond peels back the layers of deceit to reveal the terrible truth behind SPECTRE.","release_date":"2015-10-26","poster_path":"/zHx5KaKaQdZZnEUgtjcIdNcB3ka.jpg","popularity":1.279592,"title":"SPECTRE","video":false,"vote_average":7.0,"vote_count":61}],"total_pages":1,"total_results":1})
```

And the second scenario would be when a user checks his frontpage it shows all the movie titles he's added to his page.

```
%div{"ng-repeat" => "movie in movies", :class => "movie_container"}
  %h2
    {{ movie.release_date }}
  %img.poster{"ng-src" => "{{ movie.image }}"}
  .movie-info
    %h2
      {{ movie.title }}
    %a{"ng-click" => "deleteMovie(movie)"}delete
```

These are ordered by when they are created, not when they are released. The output of my JSON file is this,

```
{"id":51,"created_at":"2015-08-27T13:05:19.074Z","updated_at":"2015-08-27T13:05:19.074Z","user_id":1,"image":"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500//uereni1nSrWb6OWiJhK7FrW4pcd.jpg","title":"\n        Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice\n      ","release_date":"\n        2016-03-25\n      "}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use date as a string getter to the field im `orderBy`. I suggest you create a custom function that turns you element into a value. This value can be derived by turning your JSON date string in a date object (e.g. using momentjs) and then get the absolute time in seconds.

Comment: `orderBy:'release_date` This actually works. Didn't think the answer would be this obvious.